# How to make one class recognize another class in Java

Tags: java

So I have these two simple classes, the thing i don't understand why I am not getting the output that im expecting.

```
public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
            Greetings Test;
        }
}
```

and this

```
public class Greetings {
    

    private
     String name;
     String lastname;
     
 public
  void Greeter (String FName,String Lname)
 {
     name=FName;
     lastname=Lname;
 }
  Greetings ()
 {
      System.out.println("\nHello, World!"); 
 }
 
}
```

I was expecting the program to output "Hello, World!" two times, (one from inside the main and the  default constructor) but it only says one time. Can someone point out where I might have gone wrong.

Comment: Your object "Test" is NULL you have to initialize an instance with new Greetings();

Comment: Java is not like C++. Just declaring a variable of type `Greetings` does not create an object and call its constructor. You have to create the object yourself: `Greetings test = new Greetings();`

Answer (score 3):

Well, you declare a variable `Test` which is indeed of type `Greetings`, but you never create a `Greetings` instance.

Use `Greetings test = new Greetings()` instead. The `new` keyword is used to actually create a new instance of the class, and executes the appropriate constructor.

Then another thing: you format your *access modifiers* as if they belong to multiple variables or method declarations<sup>1</sup>. They don't. In your example, only `name` will be `private`, but `lastname` has no access modifier, which makes it *package-private*.

At last: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions. Class names are written in PascalCase, variable and method names are written in camelCase, so they start with lowercase.

---

<sup>1</sup> I suspect you are borrowing this idea from C++.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have not assigned Greetings object to the variable Test.
You can do that by writing

```
 Greetings Test = new Greetings();
```

Without this assignment, the constructor for the class Greetings will not be invoked.